# How to add YouTube videos to watching queue?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have a list of youtube video links on a page. I want to let user mark interesting ones, programatically add them to a watching queue, and then forward a user to YouTube where they can watch all those videos in sequence. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think youtube has a feature to access yt quicklist etc, but you can easily do it with youtube javascript api, if is it ok that the videos gonna be played inside your site.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

Embed a youtube player with js api in your site, then you can make a simple js array for queue.

If this solution is ok for you, i gonna write some more details about it, if you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks. No need for more details, I know about embedded player. If there is no other answers I'll accept it though.